# nginx Configuration for yii2 angular app

Tags: angularjs, nginx, yii2, friendly-url

I created a yii2 rest Angular app which is working perfect in apache server,
I need to change server to nginx.
This is my nginx configuration

```
  server {
    charset              utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    listen               8888;
    server_name          careers;
    root                 "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/careers";

    access_log           /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log            /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        root    "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/careers";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /careers-api {
        client_max_body_size 2000M;
        alias  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/careers/careers-backend/api/web;
        try_files  $uri /careers-backend/api/web/index.php?$args;

        location ~* ^/careers-api/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files  $uri /careers-backend/api/web/$1?$args;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\. {
      deny all;
    }

  }
```

It works for my angular app, but my yii2 api is not working, only I can only access default url `site/index` for every url that I given. Ps: Pretty url is enabled in my yii2 app.

Folder structure

```
-- root Folder(Angular App Index)
--- root/careers-backend/api/web (Yii2 App index)
```

Any Idea ? I am new with nginx server.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/vagrant/nginx/app.conf ?

Comment: But it is for front-end and back-end in different server, I need both in one server